MySQLDriverCS Error: wrong query.You have an error in your SQL syntax;

        public bool InsertGuildShare(string RoleName, int RoleID, double Share, int GuildID, int Rank, int FamilyID, string FamilyName)
        {
            MySQLConnection conn = null;

            try
            {

                conn = this._Database.DBConns.PopDBConnection();

                string cmdText = "Insert into t_guildshare(RoleID,Share,GuildID,RoleName,Rank,FamilyID,FamilyName) VALUES (" + RoleID + "," + Share + "," + GuildID + ",`" + RoleName + "`," + Rank + "," + FamilyID + ",`" + FamilyName + "`)";

                MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand(cmdText, conn);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                GameDBManager.SystemServerSQLEvents.AddEvent(string.Format("+SQL: {0}", cmdText), EventLevels.Important);

                cmd.Dispose();
                cmd = null;

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogManager.WriteLog(LogTypes.Guild, "BUG :" + ex.ToString());

                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (null != conn)
                {
                    this._Database.DBConns.PushDBConnection(conn);
                }
            }
        }
       

error message folder
2024-05-06 00:00:01 BUG :MySQLDriverCS.MySQLException (0x80004005): MySQLDriverCS Exception: MySQLDriverCS Error: wrong query.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rank,FamilyID,FamilyName) VALUES (202591,2.58,100035,A_The_LamSao,10,2,NoMerc' at line 1 Insert into t_guildshare(RoleID,Share,GuildID,RoleName,Rank,FamilyID,FamilyName) VALUES (202591,2.58,100035,A_The_LamSao,10,2,NoMercy`)
at MySQLDriverCS.DirectStatement.ExecuteNonQuery()
at GameDBServer.Logic.GuildLogic.GuildManager.InsertGuildShare(String RoleName, Int32 RoleID, Double Share, Int32 GuildID, Int32 Rank, Int32 FamilyID, String FamilyName) in C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\KT\SeverFile\Server-khac\s1\GameDBServer\GameDBServer\Logic\GuildLogic\GuildManager.cs:line 621
Thanks a lot

That is absolutely the wrong way to compose SQL queries. Always, always always use parameters.  Metric tons of electrons have been spent explaining the problem and advising solutions.  They are everywhere. Help yourself

BackQuotes are used for Table Name or Column Name. If you are passing values to the parameters in values(x,x,x) and its a string literal use Single Quotes like 'string value'
 public bool InsertGuildShare(string RoleName, int RoleID, double Share, int GuildID, int Rank, int FamilyID, string FamilyName)
            {
                MySQLConnection conn = null;
    
                try
                {
    
                    conn = this._Database.DBConns.PopDBConnection();
    
                    string cmdText = "Insert into t_guildshare(RoleID,Share,GuildID,RoleName,Rank,FamilyID,FamilyName) VALUES (" + RoleID + "," + Share + "," + GuildID + ",'" + RoleName + "'," + Rank + "," + FamilyID + ",'" + FamilyName + "')";
    
                    MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand(cmdText, conn);
    
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
                    GameDBManager.SystemServerSQLEvents.AddEvent(string.Format("+SQL: {0}", cmdText), EventLevels.Important);
    
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    cmd = null;
    
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogManager.WriteLog(LogTypes.Guild, "BUG :" + ex.ToString());
    
                    return false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (null != conn)
                    {
                        this._Database.DBConns.PushDBConnection(conn);
                    }
                }
            }

